# Scroll locking on bootstrap4 modal when scrolling on content which has already reached the top

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap 4 modal with scrollable content.
If I'm on the top of the content and I try to scroll downwards (which won't do anything as I'm already on the top of the scrollable content ) and then whilst still holding the touch (touchend has still not occured here) and then I try to scroll the other way, scrolling is **locked** and won't work until I left go of the touch (touchend occurs) and then now try to scroll in the other direction. 
I'm having this difficulty on touch devices (regardless of os).

This may not be a bug and instead was intended but I'm unable to think of a way to change the behaviour so that I can continuously scroll even if were already at the top.

[image]

codepen.io/heychris/pen/dMExrG
recreate steps - open developer tools in chrome, change to a touch device such as iPhone X

Comment: You just want the scroll in between the modal body right?

Comment: Okay, I will do it. Give me some time.

Comment: Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302241/modal-dialog-with-fixed-header-and-footer-and-scrollable-content

Comment: Wait I am sending you code.

Comment: `@JARRRRG` You can solve scrolling issue without write single line of css code, If using **Bootstrap4** library. So put **modal-dialog-scrollable** class with **modal-dialog** class.

Answer (score 2):

i think this cover your problem

```
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* has to be scroll, not auto */
  float: left;
}

.touch {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

```
<div class="touch">
<h3>Smooth</h3>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will attempt to implement this later today and report back to you. Will also produce a codepen to demonstrate.

Comment: Tried this, unable to fix it with this

Answer (score 1):

> You have to set the `height` of the `.modal-body` in and give it
>   `overflow-y: auto`. Also reset `.modal-dialog` overflow value to
>   `initial`

.

See the working (an idea):

```
.modal{
    display: block !important; /* I added this to see the modal, you don't need this */
}

/* Important part */
.modal-dialog{
    overflow-y: initial !important
}
.modal-body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 40vh;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.modal{
    display: block !important;
}
.modal-dialog{
      overflow-y: initial !important
}
.modal-body{
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="overflow-y: scroll; max-height:85%;  margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom:50px;"> 
        <div class="modal-content"> 
            <div class="modal-header"> 
                <h3 class="modal-title">ASDFASDFASDFASDF</h3> 
            </div> 
            <div class="modal-body">ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
          ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
          ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
          ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
          ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
          ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
          ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
          ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
          ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
          ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
          ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
          ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF</div> 
            <div class="modal-footer">ASDFASDFASDFASDF</div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will attempt to implement this later today and report back to you. Will also produce a codepen to demonstrate.

Comment: Tried the example and tried to apply these styles to my local example but still not working for me. Have upvoted for trying. Thank you

Comment: Can you share that example may be something overriding it, n Thanks for up-vote

Comment: @JARRRRG i have updated my answer. I add `height` in `vh` rather then pixel so that the `scroll` adjust according to view-port like this `.modal-body {    height: 40vh;    overflow: scroll;}` You can set its value according to view-port.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually **Bootstrap 4** default functionality, you can review the official documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/).

To override the functionality and add scroll on **modal-body** you have to write some **CSS**.

```
.modal-body {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 224px);
}
```

I just apply **overflow** and **max-height** CSS property on **modal-body** element and also use **calc** property in **max-height** to less **modal-header, modal-footer** and extra **margin** from **modal-body**.

Below you can find working code snippet and i also create [CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/creativesiddi/pen/dyPVLgZ). Try this i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.modal-body {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 224px);
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
        <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.</p>

        <h4>Popover in a modal</h4>
        <p>This <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-secondary popover-test" title="A Title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?">button</a> should trigger a popover on click.</p>

        <h4>Tooltips in a modal</h4>
        <p><a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="Tooltip">This link</a> and <a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="Tooltip">that link</a> should have tooltips on hover.</p>

        <hr>

        <h4>Overflowing text to show scroll behavior</h4>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>

<div class="bd-example" style="padding-bottom: 24px;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: `@Hassan` You can solve scrolling issue without write single line of css code, If using Bootstrap4 library. So put **modal-dialog-scrollable** class with **modal-dialog** class.

Comment: I'm going to test this today and get back to you, kind regards

Comment: I tested in your codepen and it doesn't actually fix the issue. I have still however upvoted.

Comment: @JARRRRG i just update my codepen code with the css updates, you can review it and if you are facing any issue on codepen you can use above code snippet. Thanks

Comment: Thanks ill give it a go when I get a chance @HassanSiddiqui

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to scroll header and footer of modal then you can use ***modal-dialog-scrollable*** which ***predefined*** class in bootstrap4.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalScrollable">
  Launch Demo Modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalScrollable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
         <br>
         <strong>Last Text</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm going to test this today and get back to you, kind regards

Comment: Nope this doesn't fix it. I mean my content is scrolling but it's getting locked when scrolling in a particular way. I have however still upvoted your attempt. Thanks.